# Rails 4 Linking to records in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have built a mailer that notifies users of a change to a page they are tracking that contains product info.  I cannot seem to get the link to the page correct.  In this case,

`<%= link_to @page_update.page.product.name, pages_url(@page_update.page) %>`

I end up with a link to http://www.mydomain.com/pages.123

When I am hoping for http://www.mydomain.com/pages/123

I can provide more info if necessary, but I imagine since I'm so new to this that there's something simple going on here (I hope).

Comment: can you provide the relevant part of your `config/routes.rb` ?

Comment: I've got 'resources :pages' in routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use page_url instead of pages_url

```
<%= link_to @page_update.page.product.name, page_url(@page_update.page) %>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That did the trick!  Simple fix, thanks.